# How to delete records in JPA with greater than condition?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, ejb

I want to delete the records from a PGSQL database table(ContainerTypeRule) whose id(rule_id) is greater than 10000.
I am creating a query in JPA like as follows

```
public void deleteAllTestRules(long startID){
    em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ContainerTypeRule WHERE rule_id > ?startID", ContainerTypeRule.class)
            .setParameter("startID", startID)
            .executeUpdate();
}
```

But I am getting the error like this.

```
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [DELETE FROM ContainerTypeRule WHERE rule_id > ?startID]. 
[46, 54] The positional input parameter ''{0}'' cannot use non-Integer characters.
```

How can I formulate correct query for 'id greater than 10000' condition in my JPA query.

Comment: Use either `?0` for positional parameters or `:startID` for named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You must use : not ?

```
DELETE FROM ContainerTypeRule WHERE rule_id > :startID
```

Answer (score 0):

- The problem is in writing the query parameters.

1. You can either use *positional parameters* and use **'?'**. **ex:** `DELETE FROM ContainerTypeRule WHERE rule_id > :startID`
2. Or you can use *named parameters* and use **':'**.
   **ex:** `DELETE FROM ContainerTypeRule WHERE rule_id > ?1`

- for more info: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-query-parameters